# remove default values from an object

Tags: javascript

I have two javascript objects:

```
var a = {
    x: 1, 
    y: {
        faz: 'hello', 
        baz: ''
    },
    z: [1, 2]
};


var defaults = {
    x: 2,
    y: {
        faz: '', 
        baz: ''
    },
    z: [1, 2]
};
```

I want to only keep the fields of `a` that are **different** from the default:

```
a = remove_defaults(a, defaults); // <---- i need this fnc
{
    x: 1,
    y: {
        faz: 'hello'
    }
}
```

The goal is to remove default values from an object that serves as a state (via URL). The state can have nested fields, so a shallow compare is not enough. The leaf values are all primitive (number, string, bool).

*(this is a bit like the opposite of `underscore.js`'s `_.defaults()` method)*

What is the best way to achieve this?

---

The solution can use `underscore.js` if that helps, but no `jquery`.

Comment: Recursively iterate over the properties and compare their values. There is no built-in method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My own take:

```
function no_defaults(obj, defaults) {
    if ((obj instanceof Array) && (defaults instanceof Array)) {
        var result = _.difference(obj, defaults);
        return _.isEmpty(result) ? undefined : result;
    }
    if ((obj instanceof Array) || (defaults instanceof Array))
        return _.clone(obj);
    if (typeof obj == "object" && typeof defaults == "object") {
        var result = {};
        for (var prop in obj) {
            var res = prop in defaults ? no_defaults(obj[prop], defaults[prop]) : _.clone(obj[prop]);
            if (res !== undefined)
                result[prop] = res;
        }
        return _.isEmpty(result) ? undefined : result;
    }
    return _.isEqual(obj, defaults) ? undefined : _.clone(obj);
}
```

---

Note this deep-processes objects, but not arrays. Arrays are only processed for shallow difference of their direct elements -- if the elements themselves need `no_default`ing, this function won't do. But this is fine for my intended use case.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
function removeDuplicates(a, defaults, result) {
  for (var i in a) {
    if (i in defaults) {
      if (typeof a[i] == "object" 
          && typeof defaults[i] == "object"
          && Object.prototype.toString.call(defaults[i]) !== '[object Array]') {
        result[i] = removeDuplicates(a[i], defaults[i], {});
      } else if (a[i] !== defaults[i]) {
        result[i] = a[i];  
      }
    } else {
      result[i] = a[i];
    }
  }

  return result;
}


var result = removeDuplicates(a, defaults, {});
```

Comment: Cheers! But what is the `a[i] &&` part for? That will ignore everything falsy, like `false`, `0`, `''`, `undefined`, which seems like a bug?

Comment: Oh, i just realized there's a massive bug there -- all copied fields go to the global scope of `result`, instead of into their respective subfields!

Answer (score 1):

```
function remove_defaults(obj, defaults) {
  for (var i in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[i] == 'object') {
      obj[i] = remove_defaults(obj[i], defaults[i]);
      continue;
    }
    if (defaults[i] !== undefined && obj[i] == defaults[i]) {
      delete obj[i];
    }
  }
  return obj;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ybVGq/

Comment: This leaves the `z` array in the result. I think @ioseb's solution is better, because that also deletes nested objects once they are completely empty (=all inner values were equal to default).

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that. That's because I was using `delete` instead of creating a whole new array.