# Get the difference object from two object in typescript/javascript angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, lodash

I am trying to get the change object from two objects using typescript in angular.

For example

```
this.productPreviousCommand = {
"id": "60f910d7d03dbd2ca3b3dfd5",
"active": true,
"title": "ss",
"description": "<p>ss</p>",
"category": {
    "id": "60cec05df64bde4ab9cf7460"
},
"subCategory": {
    "id": "60cec18c56d3d958c4791117"
},
"vendor": {
    "id": "60ced45b56d3d958c479111c"
},
"type": "load_product_success"
```

}

```
model = {
"active": true,
"title": "ss",
"description": "<p>ss sss</p>",
"category": "60cec05df64bde4ab9cf7460",
"subCategory": "60cec18c56d3d958c4791117",
"vendor": "60ced45b56d3d958c479111c",
"tags": []
```

}

Now the difference between two objects are  `description: "<p>hello hello 1</p>"`. So I want to return `{description: "<p>hello hello 1</p>"}`

I used lodash https://github.com/lodash/lodash

```
import { transform, isEqual, isObject, isArray} from 'lodash';

function difference(origObj, newObj) {
  function changes(newObj, origObj) {
    let arrayIndexCounter = 0
    return transform(newObj, function (result, value, key) {
      if (!isEqual(value, origObj[key])) {
        let resultKey = isArray(origObj) ? arrayIndexCounter++ : key
        result[resultKey] = (isObject(value) && isObject(origObj[key])) ? changes(value, origObj[key]) : value
      }
    })
  }
  return changes(newObj, origObj)
}
```

This library is not working for me, it returns the whole object using this code const `differenc = difference(this.productPreviousCommand, model);`

The output of above code is

```
{
    active: true
    description: "<p>hello hello 1</p>"
    id: "60f8f29dd03dbd2ca3b3dfd1"
    title: "hello"
    }
```

Comment: Is the code you posted yours or the one of Lodash? I don't see any `difference` function in Lodash documentation except to compare arrays. If it's yours, you'll need to provide us with a specific question after debugging.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery function to compute the difference between two JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11021893/jquery-function-to-compute-the-difference-between-two-javascript-objects)

Comment: @GaëlJ it is not one of Lodash, however I found it here https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/javascript+compare+two+objects+and+get+differences

Comment: refer this example http://jsfiddle.net/drzaus/9g5qoxwj/

Answer (score 2):

Try this function

```
differenceInObj(firstObj: any, secondObj: any): any {
        let differenceObj: any = {};
        for (const key in firstObj) {
            if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(firstObj, key)) {
                if(firstObj[key] !== secondObj[key]) {
                    differenceObj[key] = firstObj[key];
                }
                
            }
        }

        return differenceObj;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tested it? it is returing the whole object

Comment: let productPreviousCommand = {
            active: true,
            description: "<p>hello</p>",
            id: "60f8f29dd03dbd2ca3b3dfd1",
            title: "hello"
            }
            
            let model = {
            active: true,
            description: "<p>hello hello 1</p>",
            id: "60f8f29dd03dbd2ca3b3dfd1",
            title: "hello"
            }

            console.log(this.differenceInObj(productPreviousCommand, model))

Comment: Output {description: "<p>hello</p>"}

Comment: If you are not getting output as expected. Can you please share your input and expected output?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function difference(origObj, newObj) {
  const origObjKeyList = Object.keys(origObj),
    newObjKeyList = Object.keys(newObj);

  // if objects length is not same
  if (origObjKeyList?.length !== newObjKeyList?.length) {
    return;
  }

  // if object keys some difference in keys
  if (Object.keys(origObj).filter((val) => !Object.keys(newObj).includes(val))?.length) {
    return;
  }

  return Object.entries(origObj).reduce(
    (acc, [key, value]) => (newObj[key] !== value ? { ...acc, ...{ [key]: newObj[key] } } : acc),
    []
  );
}


const a = {
  active: true,
  description: '<p>hello</p>',
  id: '60f8f29dd03dbd2ca3b3dfd1',
  title: 'hello',
};

const b = {
  active: true,
  description: '<p>hello hello 1</p>',
  id: '60f8f29dd03dbd2ca3b3dfd1',
  title: 'hello',
};


console.log(difference(a, b));
```

> You can try this code.

```
function difference(origObj, newObj) {
  const origObjKeyList = Object.keys(origObj),
    newObjKeyList = Object.keys(newObj);

  // if objects length is not same
  if (origObjKeyList?.length !== newObjKeyList?.length) {
    return;
  }

  // if object keys is not same
  if (Object.keys(origObj).filter((val) => !Object.keys(newObj).includes(val))?.length) {
    return;
  }

  return Object.entries(origObj).reduce(
    (acc, [key, value]) => (newObj[key] !== value ? { ...acc, ...{ [key]: newObj[key] } } : acc),
    []
  );
}
```

Comment: It returns undefined

Comment: @SanJaisy : Please see the code snippet added.

Answer (score 0):

You can check loop through each key of the first object and compare it with the second object.

```js
function getPropertyDifferences(obj1, obj2) {
  return Object.entries(obj1).reduce((diff, [key, value]) => {
    // Check if the property exists in obj2.
    if (obj2.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      const val = obj2[key];

      // Check if obj1's property's value is different from obj2's.
      if (val !== value) {
        return {
          ...diff,
          [key]: val,
        };
      }
    }

    // Otherwise, just return the previous diff object.
    return diff;
  }, {});
}

const a = {
  active: true,
  description: '<p>hello</p>',
  id: '60f8f29dd03dbd2ca3b3dfd1',
  title: 'hello',
};
const b = {
  active: true,
  description: '<p>hello hello 1</p>',
  id: '60f8f29dd03dbd2ca3b3dfd1',
  title: 'hello',
};
const c = {
  active: true,
  description: '<p>hello hello 2</p>',
  id: '60f8f29dd03dbd2ca3b3dfd1',
  title: 'world',
};

console.log(getPropertyDifferences(a, b));
console.log(getPropertyDifferences(b, c));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a TypeScript function to compare two objects and return their differences, including nested objects, by recursively traversing the objects and comparing their properties. Here's a sample implementation:

```js
function getObjectDifferences(obj1: any, obj2: any): any {
  if (typeof obj1 !== 'object' || typeof obj2 !== 'object') {
    return obj1 !== obj2 ? [obj1, obj2] : undefined;
  }

  const keys1 = Object.keys(obj1);
  const keys2 = Object.keys(obj2);
  const uniqueKeys = new Set([...keys1, ...keys2]);

  const differences: any = {};

  for (const key of uniqueKeys) {
    const value1 = obj1[key];
    const value2 = obj2[key];

    if (typeof value1 === 'object' && typeof value2 === 'object') {
      const nestedDifferences = getObjectDifferences(value1, value2);
      if (nestedDifferences) {
        differences[key] = nestedDifferences;
      }
    } else if (value1 !== value2) {
      differences[key] = [value1, value2];
    }
  }

  return Object.keys(differences).length === 0 ? undefined : differences;
}

const obj1 = {
  name: 'John',
  age: 30,
  address: {
    city: 'New York',
    zip: '10001',
  },
};

const obj2 = {
  name: 'Jane',
  age: 28,
  address: {
    city: 'San Francisco',
    zip: '94101',
  },
};

const differences = getObjectDifferences(obj1, obj2);
console.log(differences);
```

Output

```json
{
  "name": [
    "John",
    "Jane"
  ],
  "age": [
    30,
    28
  ],
  "address": {
    "city": [
      "New York",
      "San Francisco"
    ],
    "zip": [
      "10001",
      "94101"
    ]
  }
}
```

This function `getObjectDifferences` takes two objects, recursively compares their properties, and returns an object representing the differences between them. If there are no differences, it returns `undefined`. The example provided compares two objects `obj1` and `obj2`, including nested objects within them.

Remember that this implementation is a basic example, and you can further refine it to suit your specific needs and handle various data types and edge cases.